# I need to change color for single container but it's change color for whole container

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

```
      AnimationController? controller;
       Animation<double>? animation;
      @override
      void initState() {
super.initState();
controller =
    AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 3), vsync: this)
      ..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
animation = Tween(begin: -500.0, end: 500.0).animate(controller!);
controller!.forward();
     }


     List tile = [
     [true, true, true, true],
     [true, true, true, true],
      [true, true, true, true],
       [true, true, true, true],
     ];
     String? gettw;

   Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: ListView.builder(
        reverse: false,
        itemCount: tile[0].length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          String? gettw;

          if (tile[index][0]) {
            if (gettw != 'transparent') {
              gettw = 'black';
            }
          } else if (tile[index][0] == false) {
            gettw = 'transparent';
          }
          print('gettw $gettw');
          return GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                if (tile[index][0] == true) {
                  print('working');
                  gettw = 'transparent';
                  print('gettw $gettw');
                } else if (tile[index][0] == false) {
                  gettw = 'red';
                }
              });
            },
            child: Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(0.0, animation!.value),
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
                color: (gettw == 'black')
                    ? Colors.black
                    : (gettw == 'transparent')
                        ? Colors.transparent
                        : (gettw == 'red')
                            ? Colors.red
                            : Colors.green,
                child: Text('${tile[index][0]}',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      )),
```

I animate 4 container top to bottom. If the user clicks container. The container color needs to change black to white. but color was changed in all 4 containers. gettw variable contains which color need to display in the container. Please, someone, help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColorChanger extends StatefulWidget {
const ColorChanger({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

@override
_ColorChangerState createState() => _ColorChangerState();
}

class _ColorChangerState extends State<ColorChanger> {
   List<bool> widgetActive = List.generate(4, (index){
   return false;
});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 4,
    itemBuilder: (context, index){
    
    return InkWell(
      onTap: (){
        setState(() {
          widgetActive[index] = !widgetActive[index];
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        width: 40,
        height:50,
        color: widgetActive[index] ? Colors.black:Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: ok. But i need to change the color when the user clicks the container. Container color state is black and white before the user clicks. If the user clicks then color is change to white or red.

Comment: Another issue I tap on the 1st container but the color changes in 2 container. List is updated on which color I want to show but state is not rebuild(color is not change)

Comment: updated my answer please try that one

Comment: I try your code but problem is color is not change correct container. Eg if tap on 1st container color changed on second container. If i again tap on 1st container color changed on the second container. and i use transform.translate for container top to bottom animation. So the container position is change every second. Can you help me.

Comment: Can you elaborate top to bottom animation please?

Comment: Ya sure. Actually, my app is like a piano tile game. The container will come from top to down and if the user taps. Then container color changes to transparent or white. I hope u understand.

Comment: Just for checking don't use translate and check my code once please.

Comment: Yes, I check color is changed without translate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238467/discussion-between-kaushik-chandru-and-18bcm061-joshua-jenny-sibbu).